# Weird Output Explanation

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int myfunc(char *str)
{
    char *ptr =str;
    while(*ptr++);
    printf("%s %s\n",str,ptr);
    return ptr-str-1;

}    
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", myfunc("Princess Leia"));
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Princess Leia %d

13
```

How does ptr got `%d` as string in it? And why is `ptr-str-1` is `13`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while(*ptr++);
```

increments `ptr` still when `ptr` points to the terminating 0 of the passed string, so after that it points behind the 0-terminator.

With `"Princess Leia"` as argument, `ptr` is incremented 14 times, so the return value is `14 - 1 = 13`.

What is printed is - undefined behaviour aside, since dereferencing `ptr` is usually undefined behaviour when it points after the 0-terminator (it is here), in practice - the passed-in string, and the bytes following its 0-terminator. Here `"%d\n"`, since the format string `"%d\n" happened to be stored just after`"Princess Leia".

Comment: @Danial Fischer - I tried to Run this code on 4 different platform. and Holy moses. they all give '%d'. earlier i thought it would be 'UB' but on 4 different platform that amazed me !

Comment: My gcc (4.7.2, on openSuSE 12.3 64-bit) also produces `Princess Leia %d`. But my clang (3.2) produces `clang leia.c && ./a.out 
Princess Leia 
13` no output for `ptr`. So it's not always the same.

Comment: i tried on gcc 4.3.2 and Code Block. may be it is merely a coincidence ! 
Thanks for the answer !

Comment: It's not quite merely a coincidence. It would not be surprising that gcc will lay out the string constants in the same way for the same code across different versions and platforms (of course, at some point, the algorithm determining the layout will change). Different compilers using a different layout algorithm should also not be surprising - though the design space is limited, so don't expect too much variation. If you have access to other compilers, you could try out e.g. icc or MSVC.

Comment: `while (*ptr++);` is **not** undefined behavior. It is allowed for a pointer to point to the element one-past-the-end of an array.  For example, `ptr - str` is a perfectly valid way to calculate the storage of a C string. It is not allowed, however, to *dereference* such a pointer, which `printf` does when passed one. Therefore, UB is in the call to `printf`, not in the `while`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks. /me blushes

Answer (score 3):

You got lucky.

You ended up with `ptr` pointing to the byte following the terminating null for `Princess Leia`. Not unreasonabley, this is pointing to the next `const char` that you defined, i.e. `%d\n`.

This is undefined behaviour (even if it's vaguely predictable), **don't rely on it**.